# Finding the second last greatest element in list of integers C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a

```
list<int> input = //from db of one million records
```

of **1 million** records .

Although I know that using `input.OrderByDescending().Skip(1).Take(1)` will solve the problem but if I have 1 million records , it is not a best practice to use `OrderBY`.

In this scenario which solution is the best one when we have more records?

Comment: You need to sort to find the value as there's no way to be sure which is the second to last greatest if you haven't inspected all elements. The alternative is to sort in the database layer (i.e. change your query to sort by the order you want) which is usually quicker than sorting in c# for numerous reasons.

Comment: I would not order the entire list, but only search for the two greatest numbers in an ordinary loop.

Comment: Seems easy to do but it's surprisingly harder than I expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scan the list while tracking the `max`, as well as `max2` and you'll get `O(N)` versus `O(N * log(N))` time complexity:

```
  // Maximum value
  int max  = Math.Max(input[input.Count - 1], input[input.Count - 2]);
  // Second greatest   
  int max2 = Math.Min(input[input.Count - 1], input[input.Count - 2]);

  // i >= 0: Comparing with 0 is slightly faster then with Count
  for (int i = input.Count - 3; i >= 0; --i) {
    int v = input[i];

    if (v >= max) {
      max2 = max;
      max = v; 
    }
    else if (v > max2) 
      max2 = v;
  }
```

**Edit**: In case *duplicates* should be *ignored* (see comments below) and thus the answer for `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]` should be `3`, not `4`:

```
  // Maximum value
  int max = int.MinValue;
  // Second greatest   
  int max2 = int.MinValue;

  // i >= 0: Comparing with 0 is slightly faster then with Count
  for (int i = input.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    int v = input[i];

    if (v > max) {
      max2 = max;
      max = v;
    }
    else if (v > max2 && v != max)
      max2 = v;
  }
```

Comment: Similar issue to mine, if you have a list {5,4,5} one would expect '4' as the second largest. But i'll output '5'. Could be expected or not, depending on what's required.

Comment: @Carra: So if you have *duplicates* they are should be *ignored*, am I correct? E.g. for `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]` the answer should be `3`?

Comment: @Carra I don't think that "one would expect 4", because OP claims that `Skip(1).Take(1)` linq query does what he wants, and this query doesn't ignore duplicates.

Comment: Now that I think about it, it depends on what the poster wants. He'll get '4' when using his orderby.skip(1) too so this should be OK.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by keeping track of the next max and iterating once through the list.

```
int max = Int32.MinValue;
int nextMax = Int32.MinValue;

for(int i=0; i<list.Count(); i++)
{
  if(list[i] > max)
  {
    nextMax = max;
    max = list[i]; 
  }
  else if(list[i] > nextMax)
  {
    nextMax = list[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: `list.Count` instead of `list.Count()`: no need in *Linq* here

Comment: **Counter example:** `List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };` expected: `2`, actual: `Int32.MinValue`

Comment: Added a few tests and seems OK now. A case '2,1,2' will return '2' as second largest number. Seems OK

Answer (score 2):

If your list contains only distinct values, you can also do:

```
var max = input.Max();
input.Remove(max);
var result = input.Max();
```

Comment: Should work. Iterates 2x through the list. Still better than ordering the list.

Comment: *Side effects* (item *removed*) may well spoil the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution iterating just once and using LINQ and C# 7 tuples:

```
var input = Enumerable.Range(0, 101);

var topTwo = input.Aggregate((Biggest: Int32.MinValue, SecondBiggest: Int32.MinValue),
                             (acc, next) =>
                             {
                                 if (next > acc.Biggest)
                                 {
                                     acc.SecondBiggest = acc.Biggest;
                                     acc.Biggest = next;
                                 }

                                 if (next < acc.Biggest && next > acc.SecondBiggest)   
                                     acc.SecondBiggest = next;

                                 return acc;
                             });

WriteLine(topTwo.SecondBiggest);  // 99
```